# Cannot see SDK Manager menu option in Android Studio settings

Tags: android-studio

[image: Shot from the developer web-site]

[image: My screenshot]

Here is the screenshot of Android Studio settings from the developer web site. There is a menu option named **Android SDK**

And my screenshot with black background where I cannot see that option

Does anybody know how to enable it?

Comment: have you set the SDK path?

Comment: Yes. I can open it via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager but I cannot see it in the settings.

Comment: What is your Android studio version? This screenshot is of 2.0. In latest versions menu might have been changed.

Comment: @PrashantSable my version is 2.2.2.

Comment: Even I can't see it there. May be Menu have been changed.

Comment: I have two users on my laptop. I use the same Android Studio and in one account I see that option while in the other I cannot. I don't understand why.